# Return Http Response to the Main thread an start new activity (intent) using Loopj implementation

Tags: java, android, httpresponse, loopj

I am pretty new to Java programming.
I am doing a Http Request with Async using the implementation Loopj (com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9).

The OnSuccess and OnFailure of the AsyncHttpResponseHandler are working fine.

New I want to return the HttpRespone the Main thread and display it on a new Activity (intent).

I found the method „public void onPostProcessResponse“ but the description tells the following: 
„Please note: post-processing does NOT run on the main thread, and thus any UI activities that you must perform should be properly dispatched to the app's UI thread.“
(https://loopj.com/android-async-http/doc/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpResponseHandler.html)

I really appreciate any help!!

Here is the code:

`enter code here`package com.example.myapplication;

`enter code here`import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

`enter code here`import android.content.Intent;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.ResponseHandlerInterface;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpResponse;

    public class HttpRequest extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView eMail;
    private Button CallWebService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_http_request);

        eMail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        CallWebService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call_webservice);


        Intent get_Email = getIntent(); //
        String eMail_address = getIntent().getStringExtra("id_Email");
        eMail.setText(eMail_address);


        CallWebService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"; //genutzte Bib:  implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

            new AsyncHttpClient().get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    String urlResponse = new String(responseBody);
                    CallWebService.setText(urlResponse); 

                    //String currentString = urlResponse;
                    //String [] separated =  currentString.split(",");
                    //CallWebService.setText(separated[1]);


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    CallWebService.setText("Error"); //response Body: Enthält die Antwort der URL Abfrage in Byte -> Umwandlung in string nötig
                }
            });

            }
        });

    }


}
```

All the best,
Simon

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onSuccess();

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
String urlResponse = new String(responseBody);
                CallWebService.setText(urlResponse);
}
);
```

invalidate the View must in UI Thread.